# Pass Model Variable to url() in background attribute in style html tag Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to pass the location of a static image to the url() attribute of a background image contained in the style property of a jumbotron div tag.

I've tried a few different things as shown below:

This is in my park_detail.html

```
{% extends 'full_base.html' %}
{% load tags %}
{% load static %}

{% block main_content %}
<div class = "jumbotron" style ="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.6), rgba(255,255,255,.6)), url({% static {{park.imageloc}} %});background-size:100%;background-position:left center; background-repeat:no-repeat">
```

This attempt returns an error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /waittimes/park/2/
Could not parse the remainder: '{{park.imageloc}}' from '{{park.imageloc}}'
```

I also attempted this as the bottom line:

```
<div class = "jumbotron" style ="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.6), rgba(255,255,255,.6)), url({% static '{{park.imageloc}}' %});background-size:100%;background-position:left center; background-repeat:no-repeat">
```

and it could not find the image at location:

```
/static/%7B%7Bpark.imageloc%7D%7D
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
{% static park.imageloc %}
```

as in:

```
<div class = "jumbotron" style ="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.6), rgba(255,255,255,.6)), url({% static park.imageloc %});background-size:100%;background-position:left center; background-repeat:no-repeat">
```

Comment: Worked great. Any reason why the call for a model variable is different inside a url() than a call elsewhere in a template like a image tag having src  = {{park.picture}}

Comment: @chrisrtopher28 It isn't because you are inside a `url()` (which the templating engine can't see anyway), it's because you are inside a `{% static ... %}` block (or any block that starts with `{%`). It's the same way you wouldn't need to put extra parentheses around the variable `apples` in `{% for apple in apples %}`.